# CoroutineExceptionHandler does not catch exception

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I run this code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {

    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
        println("handled")
    }

    val job = launch(exceptionHandler) {
        throw java.lang.RuntimeException("foobar")
    }

    job.join()
    println("Finished")
}
```

but the `foobar` exception is not handled and `handled` is not printed to the console

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: foobar
> at MainKt$main$1$outer$1.invokeSuspend(Main.kt:10)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:279)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
> at MainKt.main(Main.kt:3)

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `job` is not the parent job for some reason. Only the parent's handler will handle exceptions of it's children. So we need to define a scope and initialize it with a job. This job will be the parent job.

```
fun f2() = runBlocking {
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
        println("handled")
    }
    val cs = CoroutineScope(Job() + exceptionHandler)
    val job = cs.launch {
        throw java.lang.RuntimeException("foobar")
    }
    job.join()
}
```